# Android Autocompletetextview pop message when no item found in suggestion

Tags: android

I am new to android.I have search a lot but doesn't find.In `autocompletetextview` when no item found in suggestion it should show me message "No result found". But I am not able to do it.

even if this condition not work:

```
 if (!edittext.isPerformingCompletion()){
}
```

Please help me out.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Show me with some codes of your project so that we can help according to you.

Else take it as sample.

array1 - Array list.

autoText - Text selected in autocomplete textView

```
if (!array1.contains(autoText)) {
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Result Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: suppose I enter "a" in autoText. So,it will show false for above condition because array1 contains alex,adam,asin(assume).

Answer (score 0):

How do you fill your `AutoCompleteTextView`?

I guess that you are using a `Adapter` and a `List` of elements.

This way, you can directly search if the text entered by the user is contained in your list.

For example, you can do this on the onTextChanged method of your `AutoCompleteTextView`.